# I keep on getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError. I cannot fix this anyway possible

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my webapp to Google App Engine. It uses spring & maven.

When I deploy the app with "appengine:update", the server loads this message instead of my index.jsp page:

"Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.".

Upon checking the log,

here is what it says:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:469)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my pom.xml. I've tried changing org.slf4j dependency based on many suggestions from various sources without a positive result:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>    
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>     

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14-beta1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14-beta1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>




<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.5</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasny-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3-2</version>
  </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>ExcelFileParser</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>     
          <version>3.3</version>     
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.31</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.21</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If someone can please show me what's wrong and help fix my code that would be great. I feel like my brain is gonna explode. I have no idea what to do now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few logging frameworks in your appengine application. But since app engine supports just java.util.logging i suggest you remove

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Add just add the java.util.logging "version" of slf4j, like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**-- edit --**

It that doesn't help you can check whether any of your dependencies require a different logging framework with `mvn dependency:tree` and then *exclude* the dependency in your pom. You then have to add a transport from whatever logging framework was required to slf4j or java.util.logging. For example i think there is a log4j to slf4j library but i'm not sure of the name.